# better way to get attributes if object is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going to get **first name**.

```
billing_address = {
  "first_name" => "Jack"
  "last_name" => "James"
}
billing_address["first_name"]
```

But if `billing_address = nil`, it gets error.
So I updated like this.

`billing_address.present? ? billing_address["first_name"] : nil`

Is there any better way?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? You don't want to see others?

Comment: Why not just check if `billing_address` is nil? Seems like a good reason for a guard clause.

Comment: @JoshBrody, checking if billing_address is nil also works. but I just want to know the better way like the below ways.

Comment: The best way would be the null object pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern

Comment: Either don't process `billing_address` if it is `nil` or ensure that it's not `nil` in the first place. For the latter, something like `billing_adddress ||= {}` usually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the safe navigation operator:

```
nil&.[]('first_name')
# nil
{ "first_name": "Jack", "last_name": "James" }&.[]('first_name')
# "Jack"
```

Or `try`:

```
nil.try(:[], 'first_name')
# nil
{ "first_name": "Jack", "last_name": "James" }.try(:[], 'first_name')
# "Jack"
```

Comment: Sorry, it is hash.
{ "first_name" => "Jack"...}

Comment: Both versions are hashes. It changes the way you access the key ;)

Comment: ...or the old-fashioned way: `({ "first_name": "Jack", "last_name": "James" } || {})['first_name']`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, what is the difference between try(:[], 'first_name') and try('first_name')?

Comment: The first argument for try is the method to be invoked on the receiver, in that case `[]`, so `try(:[], 'first_name')` would be like `object['first_name']`. `try('first_name')` would invoke `first_name` on the object, resulting in an error if that method hasn't been defined.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your ruby version is newer than 2.3 you can use the safe navigation operator combined with [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig):

```
irb(main):001:0> { foo: 'bar' }&.dig(:foo)
=> "bar"
irb(main):002:0> nil&.dig(:foo)
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> { foo: { bar: 'baz' }}&.dig(:foo, :bar)
=> "baz"
irb(main):004:0> { foo: { bar: 'baz' }}&.dig(:x, :bar)
=> nil
```

Comment: What is the difference between bill.dig and bill&.dig?

Comment: `nil.dig(:foo)` gives a `NoMethodError`. `nil&.dig(:foo)` returns nil. http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/